# Spark Joining two large tables and storing in Hive

Tags: apache-spark, join

I am trying to join two large tables in spark and finally store it back in Hive. we could do it in Hive itself but that is taking around 1 hr hence we are trying to see whether spark can give better performance.

Below is the code snippet.

```
val m_d = hiveContext.sql("select cp,c,s,t,d,a,tr,n from m_d").repartition(2000,$"c",$"s",$"t",$"d",$"a")
//-- count 60321929
val m_e = hiveContext.sql("select cp,c,s,t,d,a,tr,n from m_e").repartition(2000,$"c",$"s",$"t",$"d",$"a")
//-- count 268135916

m_d.registerTempTable( "m_d" )
m_e.registerTempTable( "m_e" )


val joined_df = m_d.join(m_e, m_d("c") === m_e("c") 
&& m_d("s") === m_e("s") && m_d("t") === m_e("t")
&& m_d("d") === m_e("d") && m_d("a") === m_e("a") 
)

joined_df.registerTempTable( "joined_df" )
joined_df.cache()
joined_df.first()
joined_df.show()
```

Show works fine, but when even i run

```
joined_df.count
```

or

```
hiveContext.sql("create table joined_df as select * from joined_df");
```

or

```
joined_df.rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex{case (i,rows) => Iterator((i,rows.size))}.toDF("partition_number","number_of_records").collect.foreach(println)
```

i am getting below error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE

When i google the error it seems one of the partition size is exceeding 20gb or so. hence i am getting this error. but i thought the columns used in join are pretty unique for joining and should skew the data.
Also i changed the partition to 2000 to ensure data is evenly distributed.
For the stage i am getting Shuffle Read - 15.9 GB. input - 59.7 MB.

Any suggestion to improve the join or overcome the error is really appreciated.
Note, i have not tried broadcast join as i though both the data are big.

Comment: how much memory you have ?

Comment: and what is the table size ?

Comment: m_d table size is 1.11gb and m_e table size is 7.19gb. i am running this in a cluster but not sure about the memory of each node. Any idea how to check this?

Comment: spark.driver.memory,16G

Comment: `spark.driver.memory,16G
spark.executor.memory,4G
spark.sql.sources.maxConcurrentWrites,1

sc.getExecutorMemoryStatus.foreach(println)
gives me 10 executor. for each executor memory available is around 2.6 GB.

scala> sc.getLocalProperty("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions")
res60: String = 2000

scala> sc.getLocalProperty("spark.default.parallelism")
res62: String = 2000`

Please let me know if this is the memory you were looking for.

Comment: Just changed the number of partitions to 3000 using `sc.setLocalProperty("spark.default.parallelism","3000")` and `sc.setLocalProperty("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","3000")`. After that i could get the count of per partition using `joined_df.rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex{case (i,rows) => Iterator((i,rows.size))}.toDF("partition_number","number_of_records").collect.foreach(println)`. It seems the partitions are not even. first one is an example of a generic partition rest are the exceptions. 
[110, 38700]
[122, 51998967]
[684, 153434544]
[1113,287225446]
[1621,33937640]
[2799,44977425]

Comment: Interesting to know when solved, 4G executors low?

Comment: It seems when the individual tables were partitioned on the joining key the distribution was still ok. But when joined due to the nature of key on a certain partition data was getting huge - n*m. I changed the number of participants to 2000 and it worked. I am looking at other opportunities to salt the kay or filter certain data to make the distribution more proper.